# custom serialisation of sequelize toJSON

Tags: sequelize.js

currently sequelize will serialize an instance like this

```
 id: 2,
  title: 'bla bla',
  url: 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/14c6002a21ae0679',
  createdAt: Sat Mar 28 2015 18:58:42 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  updatedAt: Sat Mar 28 2015 18:58:42 GMT+0800 (SGT),
  userBookmarks:
   { createdAt: Sat Mar 28 2015 18:59:16 GMT+0800 (SGT),
     updatedAt: Sat Mar 28 2015 18:59:16 GMT+0800 (SGT),
     userId: 1,
     bookmarkId: 2 } }
```

i just want to highlight the way the relationship is serialized. this is a bookmark model and want to build or use a lib that generically modifies the relationship form userbookmarks xxx to user:[];

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a custom toJSON function:

```
var model = sequelize.define(name, attributes, {
    instanceMethods: {
        toJSON: function () {
            var values = this.constructor.prototype.toJSON.call(this); 
            // Do your magic here 
        }
    } 
});
```